# hatchet planimeter

Tags: geometry

[image]
How does [this](http://www.planimetervault.com/hatchet/hatchet.html) instrument work? Here is [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cUlKi16WdA) that demonstrates its use.

After reading [the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter) page, I still have no idea how it works. Any explanations that are easier to comprehend?

Comment: [This link](http://www.hpmuseum.org/planim.htm) may be useful. It also links to a Java planimeter with an example usage.

Comment: Originally posted to [skeptics.SE.](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4627/3677)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Robert L. Foote: [Geometry of the Prytz Planimeter.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808070) See also Mark Levi and Serge Tabachnikov [On bicycle tire tracks geometry, hatchet
planimeter, Menzin’s conjecture and oscillation
of unicycle tracks,](http://www.math.psu.edu/levi/Bicycle_papers_files/bicycle10.pdf) and Tom Apostol and M. Mnatsakanian: [The method of sweeping tangents.](http://www.mamikon.com/USArticles/Gazette.pdf)

Comment: I must be missing something, I still do not get it.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but unless it is outside of the scope of the site, we usually prefer full answers to be posted here, rather than links to answers; the point being that if those sites went down, the answers here would still be valid and helpful to future googlers.

Comment: @Blue Plenty of answers here consist of links - esp for answers whose length would be inordinate without links. It does not make sense to attempt to completely duplicate the entire mathematical corpus here. And who is "we"?

Comment: @Blue: I completely agree with Bill here. All the articles linked to should be trivial to find with the given information, even if the links should happen to break. I really think that it is exaggerated to ask for a summary of non-trivial articles written by renowned and outstanding mathematicians who evidently put a *lot* of effort into making their work understandable to as wide an audience as reasonably possible. By the way: ArXiV-links are guaranteed to be persistent.

Comment: @pic What precisely don't you get? Did you read the nice exposition in section 2 of Foote's paper. If something about this is not clear then I'm sure folks here would be glad to assist you if you ask *specific* questions about such in your question.